# Error while building AEM package from Command Line

Tags: curl, aem

I have an AEM package for backup which I have to build on the production server and then copy and install on the backup server. I am trying to run the build command from the command prompt so that I can add it to the Windows task scheduler to run it weekly.

I tried the following command to build a package using the following command:

curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json/etc/packages/my_packages/samplepackage.zip?cmd=build

I get an error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

How do I fix this error? Is there any other way to automate this backup process?

Comment: The error message indicates that it wants a request body and you didn't provide one... Maybe just add `-d ""` ?

Comment: That did not work

Comment: Just to dismiss this was a copy/paste error, are you including the domain, like localhost:4502, I see it is missing in your request.